# $ (\mathbb{R}^3, \|.\|_1) $ and $ (\mathbb{R}^3, \|.\|_\infty) $ cannot be isometric

Tags: functional-analysis

Can anyone prove that the spaces $ (\mathbb{R}^3, \|.\|_1) $ and $ (\mathbb{R}^3, \|.\|_\infty) $ cannot be isometric?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure of this? Any two norms on a finite-dimensional space are equivalent, i.e., they generate the same topology.

Comment: @user99680 This doesn't exclude the fact that an isometry cannot exist.

Comment: @user99680 Yeah, I am. This is stronger than equivalency between norms on finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Did you try to compare their unit spheres/balls?

Comment: @egreg, right, I read my own problem: show they're not homeomorphic. I guess the homeomorphism between $(-1,1))$ and $\mathbb R$ is aan example.

Comment: @julien, Compare in what sense exactly?

Comment: @Shl As Platonic bodies. (Note that $(\mathbb{R}^2,\lVert\cdot\rVert_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2,\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty)$ are isometric.)

Comment: I'm not following, guys. Sorry. Could you be a little bit more clear? Thanks.

Comment: Try to draw them and count the extreme points.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be a until ball in one of these spaces.  (That is, pick a point and look at all points with distance less than or equal to one from that point.)  Look at those points $x$ in $B$ such that there exists another unit ball $B'$ such that $B \cap B' = \{x\}$.  In one of those spaces there are 8 of these points, in the other only 6.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach this problem.

Let $f:V\to W$ is an isometry between two normed-spaces. If $v_n$ converges to $v$ in $V$ then $|v_n - v| \to 0$ and since $f$ is an isometry it follows that $|f(v_n) - f(v)| = |f(v_n-v)| = |v_n-v| \to 0$. Thus, $f(v_n)$ converges to $f(v)$ in $W$.

Thus, if you can find a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which converges with respect to one norm but not the other it means the two normed spaces are not isometric.

Comment: All the norms on $\mathbb{R}^3$ are equivalent (that is, they induce the same topology). Therefore it's impossible to find a sequence that converges with respect to one norm and not the other.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I'm sorry, but that's not the way to go about this problem.